# Allure - Aggregate Unit Test Reports

Tags: android, gradle, allure

I've got a multi-module android project, with unit tests distributed out amongst the various library modules. I've added the `io.qameta.allure-adapter` plugin to my app module, and all my library modules, and my top-level module has the `io.qameta.allure-aggregate-report` plugin applied.  When I run `:allureAggregateReport` however I get a bunch of errors about missing configurations:

```
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':allureGenerateCategories'.
   > Could not resolve project :core.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching configuration of project :core was found. The consumer was configured to find attribute 'io.qameta.allure' with value 'COPY_CATEGORIES' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
   > Could not resolve project :feature.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching configuration of project :feature was found. The consumer was configured to find attribute 'io.qameta.allure' with value 'COPY_CATEGORIES' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
   > Could not resolve project :onscene.
     Required by:
         project :
      > The consumer was configured to find attribute 'io.qameta.allure' with value 'COPY_CATEGORIES'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :onscene:
          - devDebugRuntimeElements
          - devReleaseRuntimeElements
          - flankDebugRuntimeElements
          - prodDebugRuntimeElements
          - prodReleaseRuntimeElements
          - qaDebugRuntimeElements
          - qaReleaseRuntimeElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
....
```

Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: FWIW, I'm also using the `io.qameta.allure.android.runners.AllureAndroidJUnitRunner`, and I do have an `com.android.test` project where I'm able to run ui tests.  Ultimately, I want to get the aggregated results from the unit tests, and the ui tests, and combine them into a single report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, aggregation appears to not be the way to go here.

With allure already working in my test module, I added allure to my library projects. When I run the tests, it generates `build/allure-results` for each of my modules.

I then finalize the `testDebugUnitTest` task in my library projects with a task that renames the `build/allure-results` to add the module as a prefix.

```kotlin
project.tasks.register("copyAllureResults", Copy::class) {
    from(project.layout.buildDirectory.dir("allure-results"))
    into(project.layout.buildDirectory.dir(
        "${project.path.substring(1).replace(":","_")}-allure-results"
    ))
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    tasks.getByName("testDebugUnitTest") {
        finalizedBy("copyAllureResults")
    }
}
```

Then in my test project, in my `dependencies {}`, I do:

```kotlin
    Files.walk(
        Paths.get(project.rootProject.projectDir.absolutePath)
    ).filter {
        it.isDirectory() && it.name.endsWith("-allure-results")
    }.forEach {
        logger.debug("Adding Allure Suite: ${it.name}")
        allureRawResultElements(files("${it.absolutePathString()}"))
    }
```

This adds the results for each module as a separate suite when I run `:test:allureReport`. The only downside is that `testDebugUnitTest` has to be run as a separate `./gradlew` command, so that the -allure-results folders exist during the configuration when `:test:allureReport` is run.